# looping a query from multiple variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm rewriting my newsletter mailer to throttle sending to certain domains. basically subscribers are saved in `mailer_lists` in another form, then they get assigned the mailing ip to use with that mailing ip's limit for the specified domain. the code below is my attempt to gather that information.

What I'm trying to do is pull records for query matches, looping through `$node_ip`, `$throttle_domain`, and `$throttle_speed` and then stop pulling records if it hits the global limit, then send. i'm having trouble getting it to work right..

```
function queue(){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mailer_lists` WHERE `ip` = '$node_ip' AND `email` LIKE '%".$throttle_domain."' LIMIT ".$throttle_speed."" ;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$count = $num_rows;
}
if ($count < $global){
queue();
}else{
mail();
```

Wish I had 1/2 the skills some of you have. Looking forward to any ideas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you function return number of rows like this:

```
function queue(){
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mailer_lists` WHERE `ip` = '$node_ip' AND `email` LIKE '%".$throttle_domain."' LIMIT ".$throttle_speed."" ;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
return mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

No you can make your condition:

```
if (queue() < $global){
queue();
}else{
mail();
```

Comment: this looks good, but how do i pull the data from the next record? $throttle_domain could contain dozens of destination domains and each has it's own $throttle_speed.

Comment: Do you want a function that return number of rows, and result too?

Comment: i want to pull records until it hits $global.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry, you mean with pull echo back to user or count it.

Comment: *example* - $global=200 - $throttle_domain=gmail, yahoo, hotmail /  $throttle_speed=100. i have a list of say 600 subscribers. 200 gmails, 200 yahoos, and 200 hotmails as destination domains. i would want it to pull 100 gmails, 100 yahoos, then stop pulling records because $global is maxed out.<br>after that it just waits for the next cron job. then it will pull the remaining 100 gmails and yahoos and stop again. finally it should then pull the entire 200 hotmails. i hope this makes sense..

Comment: First, global is a key word, so you can't use as variable name. limit is a key word reserved by sql, used to limit the number of returned rows, back to your question, do you have to synchronize sending emails between gmail and yahoo, $throttle_speed what is used for?

Comment: what happens is the subscribers are imported into mailer_lists. each node(ip address) has it's own throttle table. when i want to send, i assign the ip for it to use in mailer_lists. if it doesn't have an ip assigned, it isn't sent.  then i want it to pull all the information above and spit out the emails to queue into mail().

Answer (score 0):

The count in your function isn´t marked as global so is not updated.. Add global $count as the first line of the queue function.

Another issue is that when the count never reaches the global var, it will never mail. So the last batch wont be sent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really if this will work at all :D

```
<?php

function queue($ptr, $glbl){
/* each time we increment our range by $glbl */
$newPtr = $ptr + 100;
/* we use limit keyword to only fetch 100 rows each time */
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mailer_lists` WHERE `ip` = '$node_ip' LIMIT '$ptr', '$newPtr'" ;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
/* fetch the rows and send to theme an email */
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
    mail(mail($row['email'], $subject, $message));
 }

}
/* here we use a static variable to track where we are we in the range */
static $next = 0;
$i = 0;
/* sending emails*/
queue($next, $glbl);
/* put pur next beginning range in 
$next ant it will end with $next + $glbl as it in line 5 */
$next += $glbl;
?>
```